# View state in visualforce

Tags: visualforce

What is ViewState? What is governor limits in viewstate?will viewstate state maintains static and transient variable state? How to overcome viewstate Exception?

Comment: This can be the starting point of understanding view state

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce_View_State

Comment: @hemanth Have you even tried to do a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=view+state+in+visualforce&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS783US783&oq=View+state+in+visualforce&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i60j0l4.767j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) before posting as a question here? You could find a lot of info on this topic if you've done that already. Please read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking too-broad questions.

Answer (score 4):

When you attach an apex controller to a Visualforce page you may have some stuff (for example instance variables and state for the object) which you want to preserve over multiple requests for that page. For example you have a custom page to enable you to create an opportunity with multiple line items at once. The line items and the opportunity information needs to be in memory (state) for the many requests you make updating the page.

This chunk of data that you are sending back and forth to the server to keep things correct is called the viewstate. The more data you want to share between requests the bigger it gets, and if you keep on adding more you will eventually be sending too much data back and forth, not only slowing your application down but also breaking the governor limit imposed to protect from this.

How do you reduce the size of the viewstate to keep things speedy and stop the limit from being hit? Minimise the amount you are sending back and forward using partial rerenders and transient variables.

[I spoke at a webinar a few years ago for Salesforce on this and other pieces, you may find the recording useful](https://developer.salesforce.com/events/webinars/advanced_visualforce_salesforce1).